# Retorno null para um método JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

Tenho um método na minha repository que busca a ultima hora de um usuário em específico e uma data em específico também, ambos passados como argumento. Porém, se não tiver nenhum registro na data passada ele retorna null e eu preciso que no meu controller, caso o retorno seja null, ele passe a hora da máquina como parâmetro. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma, mas sempre dá NullPointerException.

Não é possível trabalhar dessa forma?

**AlocacaoRepository:**

```
@Query("select max(u.horaFim) from Alocacoes u where u.data = :data and u.agendamento.disponivel = :disponiveis")
LocalTime findbyUltimaHora(Date data, Disponiveis disponiveis);
```

**AlocacaoService:**

```
public LocalTime buscaUltimaHora(Agendamento agendamento) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date data = new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
    try {
        LocalTime hora = alocaoRepository.findByUltimaHora(data, agendamento.getDisponivel());
        return hora;
    } catch (NoResultException eX) {
        System.out.println("Nenhum valor encontrado");
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AlocacaoController:**

```
@PostMapping("/aprovar")
public String aprovarAgendamento(Alocacoes alocacoes, Agendamento agendamento) {

Agendamento agendamentoAlterado = agendamentoService.getAgendamento(agendamento.getIdAgendamento());
    agendamentoAlterado.getPedido().setStatus("aprovado");

    LocalTime horaInicio = alocacaoService.buscaUltimaHora(agendamentoAlterado);

    if (horaInicio == null) {
        alocacoes.setHoraInicio(LocalTime.now());
    } else {
        alocacoes.setHoraInicio(horaInicio);
    }

    LocalTime horaFim = LocalTime.of(horaInicio.getHour(), 0)
            .plusHours(alocacoes.getAgendamento().getPedido().getSugestaoDeHoras());

    alocacoes.setHoraFim(horaFim);

    agendamentoService.salvarAgendamento(agendamentoAlterado);
    alocacaoService.salvarAlocacao(alocacoes);
    return "redirect:/homeLider";
}
```

Comment: `alocacoes` deve ser nulo, você já experimentou debugar para achar qual propriedade é nula?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que nesse trecho (AlocacaoController):

```
LocalTime horaFim = LocalTime.of(horaInicio.getHour(), 0)
        .plusHours(alocacoes.getAgendamento().getPedido().getSugestaoDeHoras());
```

Caso o seu horaInicio seja null você está chamando o método getHour() de um objeto nulo. Tente pegar o horaInicio de seu objeto alocacoes dessa maneira:

```
    LocalTime horaFim = LocalTime.of(alocacoes.getHoraInicio().getHour(), 0)
        .plusHours(alocacoes.getAgendamento().getPedido().getSugestaoDeHoras());
```

Com isso o seu problema estará resolvido.

(ps. Seria interessante ter apontado o trecho que está dando NullPointer)

Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei resolvendo dessa forma:

```
public LocalTime buscaUltimaHoraFimDeAlocacaoDoConsultor(Agendamento agendamento) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date data = new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
    LocalTime ultimaHora = alocacaoRepository.findbyUltimaHora(data, agendamento.getDisponivel().getIdDisponivel());

    if (ultimaHora == null || ultimaHora.isBefore(LocalTime.now())) {
        int min = LocalTime.now().getMinute();
        if (min >= 0 && min < 30) {
            return LocalTime.of(LocalTime.now().getHour(), 30);
        }
        return LocalTime.of(LocalTime.now().getHour(), 00).plusHours(1);
    }
    return ultimaHora;
}
```

Assim ele não retorna nulo caso ele não traga nada do banco.